# how to build up a string url by using method in android dynamically?

Tags: java, android, url, stringbuilder

I have made one activity. In that I have to use one asynctask for api. So in that asynctask my url will be dynamically generated based on some number. I have tried as below, but it's not the proper way. Can anybody show me how I can make this url?

my sample url is:**[http://yehki.epagestore.in/app_api/order.php?customer_id=41&address_id=31&products[0][productName]=rt&products[0][product_id]=41&products[0][quantity]=2&products[0][unit]=1&products[0][unitPrice]=400&products[1][productName]=rt&products[1][product_id]=40&products[1][quantity]=2&products[1][unit]=1&products[1][unitPrice]=400](http://yehki.epagestore.in/app_api/order.php?customer_id=41&address_id=31&products%5b0%5d%5bproductName%5d=rt&products%5b0%5d%5bproduct_id%5d=41&products%5b0%5d%5bquantity%5d=2&products%5b0%5d%5bunit%5d=1&products%5b0%5d%5bunitPrice%5d=400&products%5b1%5d%5bproductName%5d=rt&products%5b1%5d%5bproduct_id%5d=40&products%5b1%5d%5bquantity%5d=2&products%5b1%5d%5bunit%5d=1&products%5b1%5d%5bunitPrice%5d=400)**

**my try is:**

```
 package com.epe.yehki.ui;

import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.R.string;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Paint.Join;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.epe.yehki.adapter.CartAdapter;
import com.epe.yehki.backend.BackendAPIService;
import com.epe.yehki.util.Const;
import com.epe.yehki.util.Pref;
import com.epe.yehki.util.Utils;
import com.example.yehki.R;

public class CartPlaceOrderActivity extends Activity {
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    Button confirm, shipping;
    RelativeLayout rl_adress;
    TextView product_name;
    String proName;
    TextView tv_adress;
    TextView tv_select_adres;
    EditText qty;
    String order_id;
    EditText price;
    TextView tv_subtotal;
    JSONArray carts = null;
    ListView cart_list;
    String myUrl;
    private CartAdapter cartContent;
    JSONObject jsonObj;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> cartList;
    HashMap<String, String> cartProduct;

    TextView tv_total;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    String method;
    ImageView back;
    RadioGroup rd;
    String add_id;
    RadioButton yes, no;
    Double min_qty, min_agree_prc, max_agree_prc, min_agree_qty, max_agree_qty, max_price, min_price;
    String placeOrderurl, pro_desc;
    String unit_id;
    String min_qty_unit_name;
    String subtotal, total;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productList;
    Intent i;
    String unit;
    String pro_id;
    JSONArray jArryCompleteOrder = null;
    JSONArray jArryPayeeKey = null;
    JSONArray jArryProductId = null;
    JSONArray jArryOrderProId = null;
    ArrayList<String> completeOrderArray = null;
    ArrayList<String> payeeKeyArray = null;
    ArrayList<String> productIdArray = null;
    ArrayList<String> orderProductIdArray = null;
    String shipCity, shipCountry, shipoAddress, shipTime;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cart_place_order);

        // FINDINLG IDS...!!
        qty = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_qty);
        price = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_price);
        rl_adress = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.btn_adress);
        product_name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_product_name);
        tv_adress = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_adress);
        tv_select_adres = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_select_adress);
        tv_total = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_total);
        tv_subtotal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_subtotal);
        back = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_back);
        confirm = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_confirm);

        yes = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.yes);
        no = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.no);
        productList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        cart_list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.cart_list);
        cartList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        completeOrderArray = new ArrayList<String>();
        productIdArray = new ArrayList<String>();
        orderProductIdArray = new ArrayList<String>();
        payeeKeyArray = new ArrayList<String>();
        new GetCartList().execute();

        // SELECT ADDRESS CLICK EVENT..!
        rl_adress.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                i = new Intent(CartPlaceOrderActivity.this, AddressListActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(i, 1);
            }
        });

        back.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                finish();
            }
        });
        confirm.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (!tv_adress.getText().toString().equals("") && tv_adress.getText().toString() != null) {

                    new GetPlaceOrder().execute();
                    System.out.println("::::::::::::PLACE ORDER API CALLED::::::::::");

                }

                else {
                    Utils.showCustomeAlertValidation(CartPlaceOrderActivity.this, "Please select adress", "Yehki", "Ok");
                }
            }

        });

    }

    // GETTING ADDRESS VALUES FROM ADDESSlIST ACTIVITY...
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent i) {

        if (resultCode == 2 && requestCode == 1) {
            add_id = i.getStringExtra(Const.TAG_ADDRESS_SHIPPING_ID);
            Pref.setValue(CartPlaceOrderActivity.this, Const.PREF_ADRESS_ID, add_id);
            i.getStringExtra(Const.TAG_ADDRESS_BUYER);
            Pref.setValue(CartPlaceOrderActivity.this, Const.PREF_ADDRESS_BUYER, i.getStringExtra(Const.TAG_ADDRESS_BUYER));
            shipCity = i.getStringExtra(Const.TAG_ADDRESS_CITY);
            shipoAddress = i.getStringExtra(Const.TAG_ADDRESS_STATE);
            shipCountry = i.getStringExtra(Const.TAG_ADRESS_COUNTRY);
            shipTime = i.getStringExtra(Const.TAG_SHIP_TIME);
            i.getStringExtra(Const.TAG_ADDRESS_TELEPHONE);
            i.getStringExtra(Const.TAG_ADDRESS_FAX);

            try {
                if (!i.getStringExtra(Const.TAG_ADDRESS_BUYER).equals("") && i.getStringExtra(Const.TAG_ADDRESS_BUYER) != null) {
                    tv_adress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    tv_adress.setText(i.getStringExtra(Const.TAG_ADDRESS_BUYER) + "\n" + i.getStringExtra(Const.TAG_ADDRESS_CITY) + "\n" + i.getStringExtra(Const.TAG_ADDRESS_STATE) + "\n"
                            + i.getStringExtra(Const.TAG_ADRESS_COUNTRY) + "\n" + i.getStringExtra(Const.TAG_ADDRESS_TELEPHONE) + "\n" + i.getStringExtra(Const.TAG_ADDRESS_FAX) + "");
                    tv_select_adres.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    System.out.println(":::::::::::::::::::VALUES::::::::::::::::::" + i.getStringExtra(Const.TAG_ADDRESS_BUYER));
                } else {
                    tv_adress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    tv_select_adres.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }

    // GETTING ORDER ID AND PALCE ORDER CONFIRAMATION CALL.....FOR WEBvIEW OR
    // WHAT...........!!!
    private class GetPlaceOrder extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Showing progress dialog

            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(CartPlaceOrderActivity.this);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
            System.out.println("==========inside preexecute===================");

            /*
             * FUNCTION FOR MAKING REQUEST URL...!!!
             */

        }

        void prepareURL() {
            Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder();
            builder.scheme("http").authority("yehki.epagestore.in").appendPath("app_api").appendPath("order.php")
                    .appendQueryParameter("customer_id", Pref.getValue(CartPlaceOrderActivity.this, Const.PREF_CUSTOMER_ID, "")).appendQueryParameter("address_id", add_id);

            for (int i = 0; i < carts.length(); i++) {
                builder.appendQueryParameter("products[" + i + "][productName]", cartProduct.get(Const.TAG_PRODUCT_NAME));
                builder.appendQueryParameter("products[" + i + "][productId]", cartList.get(i).get(Const.TAG_PRODUCT_ID));

                // and so on...
            }

            String myUrl = builder.build().toString();
            System.out.println("::::::::::::::::URL PRODUCT NAMER::::::::::::::" + myUrl);
        }

        void makeURL() {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String query = "http://yehki.epagestore.in/app_api/order.php?customer_id=" + Pref.getValue(CartPlaceOrderActivity.this, Const.PREF_CUSTOMER_ID, "") + "&address_id=" + add_id;
            sb.append(query);

            for (int i = 0; i < carts.length(); i++) {
                sb.append(("&products[" + i + "][productName]=" + cartList.get(i).get((Const.TAG_PRODUCT_NAME))));
                sb.append(("&products[" + i + "][product_id]=" + cartList.get(i).get((Const.TAG_PRODUCT_ID))));
                sb.append(("&products[" + i + "][quantity]=" + cartList.get(i).get((Const.TAG_QUANTITY))));

                sb.append(("&products[" + i + "][unit]=" + cartList.get(i).get((Const.TAG_UNIT))));
                sb.append(("&products[" + i + "][unitPrice]=" + cartList.get(i).get((Const.TAG_RETAIL_PRICE))));
            }

            myUrl = sb.toString();
            myUrl = Uri.encode(myUrl);
            System.out.println("::::::::::::::::URL PRODUCT NAMER::::::::::::::" + myUrl);

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // Creating service handler class instance
            BackendAPIService sh = new BackendAPIService();

            makeURL();

            System.out.println("::::::::::::::::My place order url:::::::::::" + myUrl);

            // Making a request to url and getting response
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(myUrl, BackendAPIService.POST);

            Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);
            System.out.println("=============MY RESPONSE FOR PLACEORDER>>==========" + jsonStr);

            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {

                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                    order_id = jsonObj.getString(Const.TAG_ORDER_ID);
                    Pref.setValue(CartPlaceOrderActivity.this, Const.PREF_ORDER_ID, order_id);
                    System.out.println("::::::::::::::::::MY order ID::::::::::::::::;++++++++++++++>>>>>>>>>>> " + order_id);

                    // FOR ORDER COMPLETION TIME....!!!
                    if (jsonObj.has(Const.TAG_COMPLETE_ORDER_TIME)) {
                        jArryCompleteOrder = jsonObj.getJSONArray(Const.TAG_COMPLETE_ORDER_TIME);
                        if (jArryCompleteOrder != null && jArryCompleteOrder.length() != 0) {
                            for (int i = 0; i < jArryCompleteOrder.length(); i++) {
                                jArryCompleteOrder.getString(i);
                                System.out.println("::::::::::::::COMPLETETION ORDER TI,E INSIDE JSON>>>>>>>>>" + jArryCompleteOrder.getString(i));

                                completeOrderArray.add(jArryCompleteOrder.getString(i));
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    // FOR PAYEE KEY...!!!
                    if (jsonObj.has(Const.TAG_PAYEE_KEY)) {
                        jArryPayeeKey = jsonObj.getJSONArray(Const.TAG_PAYEE_KEY);
                        if (jArryPayeeKey != null && jArryPayeeKey.length() != 0) {
                            for (int i = 0; i < jArryPayeeKey.length(); i++) {
                                jArryPayeeKey.getString(i);
                                System.out.println("::::::::::::::PAYEE KEY INSIDE JSON>>>>>>>>>" + jArryPayeeKey.getString(i));

                                payeeKeyArray.add(jArryPayeeKey.getString(i));
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    // FOR PRODUCT IDS......!!!
                    if (jsonObj.has(Const.TAG_PRODUCT_ID)) {
                        jArryProductId = jsonObj.getJSONArray(Const.TAG_PRODUCT_ID);
                        if (jArryProductId != null && jArryProductId.length() != 0) {
                            for (int i = 0; i < jArryProductId.length(); i++) {
                                String pro_id = jArryProductId.getString(i);
                                System.out.println("::::::::::::::PRTODUCT ID INSIDE JSON>>>>>>>>>" + jArryProductId.getString(i));

                                productIdArray.add(jArryProductId.getString(i));
                                System.out.println(":::::MY length::::::" + productIdArray.size());
                            }
                        }

                        // FOR ORDER PRODUCT IDS......!!!
                        if (jsonObj.has(Const.TAG_ORDER_PRODUCT_ID)) {
                            jArryOrderProId = jsonObj.getJSONArray(Const.TAG_ORDER_PRODUCT_ID);
                            if (jArryOrderProId != null && jArryOrderProId.length() != 0) {
                                for (int i = 0; i < jArryOrderProId.length(); i++) {
                                    jArryOrderProId.getString(i);
                                    System.out.println("::::::::::::::ORDER PRODUCT KEY INSIDE JSON>>>>>>>>>" + jArryOrderProId.getString(i));

                                    orderProductIdArray.add(jArryCompleteOrder.getString(i));
                                    System.out.println(":::::MY length::::::" + orderProductIdArray.size());
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");

            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            // Dismiss the progress dialog
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();
            // String webView = "";

            i = new Intent(CartPlaceOrderActivity.this, PaymentOptionActivity.class);
            i.putExtra(Const.TAG_ORDER_ID, order_id);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();

        }
    }

    // GET CART lIST PRODUCT PLACE ORDER.........!!!
    private class GetCartList extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Showing progress dialog
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(CartPlaceOrderActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // Creating service handler class instance
            String cartUrl = Const.API_CART_LIST + "?customer_id=" + Pref.getValue(CartPlaceOrderActivity.this, Const.PREF_CUSTOMER_ID, "");
            BackendAPIService sh = new BackendAPIService();
            // Making a request to url and getting response
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(cartUrl, BackendAPIService.GET);

            Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);
            try {
                if (jsonStr != null) {

                    jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                    total = jsonObj.getString(Const.TAG_TOTAL);

                    // Getting JSON Array node
                    if (jsonObj.has(Const.TAG_PRO_LIST)) {

                        carts = jsonObj.getJSONArray(Const.TAG_PRO_LIST);
                        if (carts != null && carts.length() != 0) {
                            // looping through All Contacts

                            for (int i = 0; i < carts.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject c = carts.getJSONObject(i);

                                String proId = c.getString(Const.TAG_PRODUCT_ID);
                                String proName = c.getString(Const.TAG_PRODUCT_NAME);
                                String wPrice = c.getString(Const.TAG_WHOLESALE_PRICE);
                                String rPrice = c.getString(Const.TAG_RETAIL_PRICE);
                                String qty = c.getString(Const.TAG_QUANTITY);
                                String subTotal = c.getString(Const.TAG_SUBTOTAL);
                                String unit_id = c.getString("unit_id");

                                String proimg = Const.API_HOST + "/" + c.getString(Const.TAG_PRODUCT_IMG);
                                cartProduct = new HashMap<String, String>();

                                cartProduct.put(Const.TAG_PRODUCT_ID, proId);
                                cartProduct.put(Const.TAG_PRODUCT_NAME, proName);
                                cartProduct.put(Const.TAG_PRODUCT_IMG, proimg);
                                cartProduct.put(Const.TAG_WHOLESALE_PRICE, wPrice);
                                cartProduct.put(Const.TAG_RETAIL_PRICE, rPrice);
                                cartProduct.put(Const.TAG_QUANTITY, qty);
                                cartProduct.put(Const.TAG_SUBTOTAL, subTotal);
                                cartProduct.put(Const.TAG_TOTAL, total);
                                cartProduct.put(Const.TAG_UNIT, unit_id);
                                cartList.add(cartProduct);

                            }
                        }
                    }

                } else {
                    Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("::::::::::::::::::got an error::::::::::::");
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            // Dismiss the progress dialog
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();

            cartContent = new CartAdapter(CartPlaceOrderActivity.this, cartList);
            cart_list.setAdapter(cartContent);
            tv_total.setText("Total:" + total);

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: what is this, in loop you are creating new `StringBuilder` on every loop itration, and assigning it something. what u wnat actually?

Comment: @Tim Dev-I have implemented as per you have suggested but can you please help me for the ?Jsonarrya to array?

Comment: You need to provide example of where your data comes from. The only thing in your code now is `=0`  I just gave a pseudo-example

Comment: @TimDev-i am posting you my whole class...can u pls tell me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure if you use a builder helper class like that you initialize it before the loop.

That said, [`UriBuilder`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.Builder.html) is a perfect solution for your problem, it's a helper class for building or manipulating url's.

Below is an example for you:

```
Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder();
builder.scheme("http")
    .authority("yehki.epagestore.in")
    .appendPath("app_api")
    .appendPath("order.php")
    .appendQueryParameter("customer_id", customer_id)
    .appendQueryParameter("address_id", address_id);

for (int i = 0; i < carts.length(); i++) {
   builder.appendQueryParameter("products["+i+"][productName]", cartList.get(i).get((Const.TAG_PRODUCT_NAME)));
   builder.appendQueryParameter("products["+i+"][productId]", cartList.get(i).get((Const.TAG_PRODUCT_ID)));
   builder.appendQueryParameter("products["+i+"][quantity]", cartList.get(i).get((Const.TAG_QUANTITY)));
   builder.appendQueryParameter("products["+i+"][unit]", cartList.get(i).get((Const.TAG_UNIT)));
   builder.appendQueryParameter("products["+i+"][unitPrice]", cartList.get(i).get((Const.TAG_RETAIL_PRICE)));

}

String myUrl = builder.build().toString();
```

Comment: hi...Thank you so much..for answer it will be help me..but thing is that "carts" is a JSONARRAY so how can i do "carts[i]"...it gives me error..:(

Comment: and it gives me such url:05-01 05:10:08.510: I/System.out(1357): ::::::::::::::::URL PRODUCT NAMER::::::::::::::http://yehki.epagestore.in/app_api/order.php?customer_id=41&address_id=70&products%5B0%5D%5BproductName%5D=null&products%5B1%5D%5BproductName%5D=null&products%5B2%5D%5BproductName%5D=null

Comment: Oh haha , I actually don't know where you get the customerid and product info from.  It's just pseudo code.  You haven't given any example on where you save and get the data from. So I just guessed. Thats why everything is `null`. It doesn't exists.

Comment: I have posted my whole code ..Now can you please help me sir?

Comment: Changed the code, the url builder should work. If your json and hashmap isn't working that's an entire different problem, and you should debug that accordingly

Answer (score 0):

You can use Spring Android Rest Template

> http://projects.spring.io/spring-android/

You can create a class with your request representation and if it is a post request you can send it as below.

```
/* user Registration screen */
    public UserAccount registerUser(UserAccount user) {
        final String url = Util.BASE_URL + "/user/register";
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        restTemplate
                .setRequestFactory(new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory());
        restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(
                new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
        ResponseEntity<UserAccount> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(url,
                HttpMethod.POST, new HttpEntity<UserAccount>(user,
                        jsonReqAndResHeaders()), UserAccount.class);
        return responseEntity.getBody();
    }
```

The above shown is the code we use to register a User. Created a UserAccount class populated it with data and sent it to the server using a POST request.

This is similar to your scenario, you can create an Order class populate all the data and just hit the server url as shown above.

If you should use a GET request and prepare a URL, but for long urls like yours its always best to go with POST.

Hope this helps. Thanks